# Extracting numbers from a text file using regex. Why option 1 does not work?

Tags: python, regex

Goal: To calculate the total of all the numbers in a text file(Refer file in link at the end). The output sum should be 313125

Problem: Option 1 returns an empty list for re.findall and thus the total is zero. I think the problem maybe that 'line' variable is not read as a string. Option 2 works as expected.

Help needed. What is wrong with the code in Option1?

Option1 :

```
import re

# read the file
fh = open(r"regex_sum_395835.txt", encoding='utf-8') 

for lin in fh: # loop to read each line in the file
    line = str(lin).strip()
    array = re.findall('[0-9]+',line) **# I think this is where the problem exists.**

print("Array is", array) *# test line to print the contents of list. It returns and empty list*

total = 0
for number in array: *# loop through the list to find total of all numbers*
    total = total + int(number)

print("Sum is", total) *# print the total of all numbers*
```

Option 2: This option works, but I want to understand why first option did not work

```
 import re

fh = open(r"regex_sum_395835.txt", encoding='utf-8').read()

array = re.findall('[0-9]+',fh)

total = 0
for number in array:
    total = total + int(number)

print("Sum is", total)
```

[Link to text file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QRqL57mo4gMMiSCSWIdi11fiDvu22vF3/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code is reassigning `array` for every line.  The last line of the file has no numbers so the final value is an empty list.

Rearrange like so to get the answer:

```
import re

# read the file
with open(r"regex_sum_395835.txt", encoding='utf-8') as fh:
    total = 0
    for line in fh: # loop to read each line in the file
        array = re.findall('[0-9]+',line) # I think this is where the problem exists.**
        for number in array: # loop through the list to find total of all numbers*
            total += int(number)

print("Sum is", total) # print the total of all numbers*
```